# Group Rows to in Oracle SQL to achieve unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following rows in a SQL Table

```
Col1    Col2  Col3  Col4
CABA    B08    3    0000000000017
BA      A06    4    0000000000018
CABA    B08    3    0000000000018
CABA    B06  1.5    0000000000019
BA      A07    5    0000000000021
CABA    B04   0.5   0000000000021
```

As a result, I would like to group common Col4 and create IDs ColD like the following

```
Col1    Col2  Col3  Col4            Col5
CABA    B08    3    0000000000017   ARB08
BA      A06    4    0000000000018   ARA06B08
CABA    B08    3    0000000000018   ARA06B08
CABA    B06  1.5    0000000000019   ARB06
BA      A07    5    0000000000021   ARA07B04
CABA    B04   0.5   0000000000021   ARA07B04
```

Is there a way we can achieve this using Oracle SQL

Comment: Again `listagg()` :)

Comment: How are you constructing the final column?  You should explain the rules.

Comment: Grouping on Col4, and then Concatenating 'AR' with Col2

Comment: Is a sequence not adequate? Or an identity column in Oracle 12 and beyond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` as a window function:

```
select
    t.*,
    'AR' || listagg(col2, '') 
        within group(order by col2) 
        over(partition by col4) col5
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=12ad83959d252b6573f3650d0a1debd1)**:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5    
:--- | :--- | ---: | ---: | :-------
CABA | B08  |    3 |   17 | ARB08   
BA   | A06  |    4 |   18 | ARA06B08
CABA | B08  |    3 |   18 | ARA06B08
CABA | B06  |  1.5 |   19 | ARB06   
BA   | A07  |    5 |   21 | ARA07B04
CABA | B04  |   .5 |   21 | ARA07B04
```